# Как проверить правильно ли настроен виртуальный хост на VPS сервере?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps

Есть VPS  на нем ubuntu,  там nginx, настраивал виртуальный хост, еще не связывал с доменом. Как проверить правильно ли настроен виртуальный хост? Если на локале, то в браузере, а если на vps то как?
В ошибках пишет 2015/09/07 15:10:20 [emerg] 16642#0: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wordfray.com:2

Настройки сайтов

1-й

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    charset utf-8;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    server_name smartcook.info www.smartcook.info;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

        location @phalcon {
            rewrite ^/resource/(.+)$ /resource/index.php?_url=$1 last;
        }

        location /resource/ {
            index index.php;
            if ($uri !~ ^/resource) {
                rewrite ^/resource(.*)$ /resource$1;
            }
            try_files $uri $uri/ @phalcon;
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

2-й

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/wordfray.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name wordfray.com www.wordfray.com;

    location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: тоже в браузере. благо, «[их есть](http://rus-linux.net/po.php?name=/po/po-08.koi#brousers)»

Comment: там есть только ssh

Comment: там **обязательно** есть много программ. но, в конце концов, если зачем-то удалены все браузеры, должны присутствовать http-клиенты: хотя бы wget или curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем один товарищ подсказал, на вопросах он не зареган так что вместо него напишу. 
 listen 80 default_server; Убираем  от сюда default_server
И все работает 
Еще вот так вот прописываем ДНС
http://prntscr.com/8dlcsd
Проверить можно wget, скачав страницу на сервере

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в hosts

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX example.com
```

где XXX - это ip ВДСки,
example.com - ваш домен

Comment: И что мне это даст?

Comment: насколько я понял у себя на локале прописать в файле, так сделал но попадаю на основной домен

Comment: значит не правильно прописали. Какая ОС на локальной машине?

Comment: проверить куда попадаете командой ping example.com - должен быть ip вашей ВДСки

Comment: Так там 2 сайта на 1-м ip  увижу только ip